# How can Gmail's Mail be accessed by IMAP using OAuth2 authentication or retrieve using Gmail API in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail, imap, oauth-2.0

is there any way for accessing Gmail's Mail by IMAP using OAUTH2 authentication in asp.net c#?

using google api, I am able to get the MessageID. But unable to retrieve the details of that message:

```
var gmailservice = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                        ApplicationName = appName,
                    });
 List<Message> objList = ListMessages(gmailservice, "me", AnyFromEmailAddress);

foreach (Message objM in objList)
 {
     // I can retrieve  objM.Id but how to get message detail?
 }
```

Or is there any free IMAP client which use OAUTH2 for login like Limilab's Mail.dll

Comment: Not that I know about, I paid for Limilabs component, it works like a champ. It's really inexpensive when you think about the time it's going to save you.  I been using their component since 2008.

Comment: Did you implement the the sample from this [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet#step_3_set_up_the_sample)?

Comment: sorry for late reply as I was suffering from fever. Yes, I implemented from that link and the email's html was missing.

Answer (score -1):

Using [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) and Google's OAuth2 framework from NuGet, you can do it like this:

```
using (var client = new ImapClient ()) {
    client.Connect ("imap.gmail.com", 993, true);

    var certificate = new X509Certificate2 (@"C:\path\to\certificate.p12", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential (new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer ("your-developer-id@developer.gserviceaccount.com") {
        // Note: other scopes can be found here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes
        Scopes = new[] { "https://mail.google.com/" },
        User = "user@gmail.com"
    }.FromCertificate (certificate));

    // Note: result will be true if the access token was received successfully
    bool result = await credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync (cancel.Token);

    // use the access token as the password string
    client.Authenticate ("user@gmail.com", credential.Token.AccessToken);

    // ...

    client.Disconnect (true);
}
```